# combine two data frames with all posible combinations

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I have 2 data frames.
How I can make something like `tidyr::complete` with them using `tidyverse`?

My data:

```
df <-data.frame(a=letters[1:2] )
df1<-data.frame(one=1:2)
```

Expected Result:

```
a 1 
b 1
a 2
b 2
```

Thx!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two data frames with all combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880977/merge-two-data-frames-with-all-combinations)

Comment: are your data frames multiple columns? If yes, can you provide an example and expected results with multiple columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this particular example I think you can just use the merge function. As a standard its arguments all.x and all.y are set to TRUE, so it automatically creates all combinations since the dataframes do not have any variables or values in common.

```
df <-data.frame(a=letters[1:10] )
df1<-data.frame(one=1:10)

dfcomb <- merge(df,df1)
dim(dfcomb) 
[1] 100   2 #gives 100 rows and 2 columns
```

Comment: What R version are you using? From what I check the default parameters are `merge(all=FALSE, all.x=all, all.y=all)`. So the default is actually False, not True!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `tidyr::crossing`

```
tidyr::crossing(df, df1)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  a       one
#  <chr> <int>
#1 a         1
#2 a         2
#3 b         1
#4 b         2
```

or `expand_grid`

```
tidyr::expand_grid(df, df1)
```

Comment: I met this question, and the answer is great . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for your specific example, expand.grid can be used:

```
expand.grid(df[[1]],df1[[1]])
  Var1 Var2
1    a    1
2    b    1
3    a    2
4    b    2
```